# How do i link Visual Studio applications over LAN

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, lan

I have created a VS application , I have installed a copy on another computer and I wish to link them via LAN so that if `settings` are canged in one , the others setings will also be saved .

for example this setting

i created a new `name` in the sttings are and call it "AdminIn" and set its type it `integer` , its `scope` to `user` and set its  value to 0

```
    Dim AI As New My .MySettings

 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    AI.AdminIn = AI.AdminIn + 1
Ai.SAve()

End Sub
```

now how can AI also be updated in the other application on the other computer .

How do I connect via LAN and accomplish this ?

Comment: Put the settings file in a common location?

Comment: could you expound on what you are alluding to

Comment: Would you be okay if only one was open at one time?

Comment: yeah ,it would be fine is only one was open at any time

Comment: Put the file in a directory or network drive that both machines have access to and then A) have each instance of the application copy the file to the local machine or B) have each instance of the application open the file to read it's contents and then store/implement the settings in the manner of your choosing.

Comment: Seeing as `AdminIn`  scope is set to "User" then it is imperative that i create a central area where my settings are stored and can be written and read from . I realised .
since `AdminIn` value is specific to each user ....
so i'm taking the Setting.vb file and putting it in a central location.

each time a user carries out a specific action information is written to and read from the setting.vb file . but how do i instigate the read write ability over LAN ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this link that provides some example code to modify application-scoped variables from `My.Settings` that might be useful.  I've tested it out with a simple form with a timer and a label showing me the current value of the `AdminIn` setting, and it seems to work.  The timer updates the label on every instance of the form by checking the reloaded `My.Settings` value.  The variable would need to be application scoped in order to be accessible to all users on any machine that may run the executable.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19211/Changing-application-scoped-settings-at-run-time

Here's the form code that I put together to keep the current admin count up-to-date.  Very simplistic, but it seems to do the job neatly.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        'Decrement the AdminIn count when the current instance of the form is closed.
        Me.tmrAdminCheck.Stop()
        ChangeMyAppScopedSetting((My.Settings.AdminIn - 1).ToString)
        'Reload the .exe.config file to synchronize the current AdminIn count.
        My.Settings.Reload()
        My.Settings.Save()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Increment the current AdminIn count when a new instance of the form is loaded
        ChangeMyAppScopedSetting((My.Settings.AdminIn + 1).ToString)
        'Reload the .exe.config file to synchronize the current AdminIn count.
        My.Settings.Reload()
        My.Settings.Save()

        Me.lblAdminsIn.Text = "Current Admins In: " & My.Settings.AdminIn.ToString
        'Start the timer to periodically check the AdminIn count from My.Settings
        Me.tmrAdminCheck.Enabled = True
        Me.tmrAdminCheck.Interval = 100
        Me.tmrAdminCheck.Start()
        Me.Refresh()
        Application.DoEvents()
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmrAdminCheck_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrAdminCheck.Tick
        'Reload the .exe.config file to synchronize the current AdminIn count.
        My.Settings.Reload()
        Me.lblAdminsIn.Text = "Current Admins In: " & My.Settings.AdminIn.ToString
        Me.Refresh()
        Application.DoEvents()
    End Sub
End Class
```

I've found a couple of things with this method, and they relate to what others have already mentioned in their comments:

1. The application's .exe.config file must be in an accessible location (the CodeProject example defaults to the application's executable directory).  Of course, you could save the settings to an INI file or some other configuration file in another shared directory and accomplish a similar thing, but this method uses the `My.Settings`.
2. You'll may want to do some additional checking for the possibility
   of two people attempting to get in at exactly the same time.  If
   that happens, the configuration file will still be open and locked,
   and the new `AdminIn` value won't be saved.  The CodeProject example
   doesn't have any exception handling, but you could easily work this
   functionality into the exception handling by making a recursive call
   to the Sub.

Otherwise, this seems to be a totally viable method of accomplishing what you're talking about.

Comment: I will try out this example and get back to you . first I will set my AdminIn scope to Application

Comment: Yeah, the application scope variables for `My.Settings` are all read-only, which is why, if you want to use `My.Settings` and allow multiple users to be able to update them, you'll need to use something like what's in that CodeProject article to "manually" edit the `.exe.config` file.  Then, you can use a timer to check that file periodically for any changes to its value from other users.  Of course, you can always use an external configuration file (like the other users suggested) and store the value in a Public variable, but you wouldn't be using `My.Settings` anymore.